# How to jump to a new website when Selenium cannot load a link due to an error?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list of about 13.000 websites. From those each of those links, I intend to scrape information one by one by means of Python, Beautiful Soup and Selenium.

For most websites, the scraping process works fine. However, Selenium occasionally encounters a problem with a specific link. For instance, it gave the following error message when it loaded one of them:

`WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)`

When I went to the driver and reloaded the page manually, it worked well. Unfortunately, the error stopped the whole scraping process. When I run the process again, I wish to prevent this from happening another time.

Here the first part of the loop I use to scrape the links:

```
for house in all_nd:
    if str(requests.head(house)) == '<Response [200]>':
        driver.get(house)
        
        house_html = driver.page_source
        house_soup = BeautifulSoup(huis_html)
```

Here, all_nd is a Python 3 list of strings of websites to houses and apartments. They're all prepended with 'https://'.

**Question**

> How do I ensure that the scraping process is not stopped by a (temporary) error from a website? How do I jump to the next link in the list and continue with the for loop?

Comment: Possibly this exception occurs because of some resource leakage. Normally browser is not supposed to go through 13.000 websites one after an other in the same session in a short time. So it's possible that after the first exception all the following links or a part of them will fail too.

Comment: @Prophet Thank you, good point. Do you know whether there are ways to prevent resource leakage in Python?

Comment: I don't know. Also I guess it's not Python rather than the browser or Selenium web driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `try-except` and in case of exception to continue to the next iteration.

```
for house in all_nd:
  try:
    if str(requests.head(house)) == '<Response [200]>':
        driver.get(house)
        
        house_html = driver.page_source
        house_soup = BeautifulSoup(huis_html)  
  except:
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying this right now. This is probably something I should've known, seems like quite a basic yet effective coding solution.

Comment: Sure, try-catch is a basic way for exceptions treatment.